# Same function but different result

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Cross post [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/178774/same-function-but-different-result/)

---

This is my private function for show those ROI with red color.

```
Mat highlight(Mat srcImg, Mat mask) {
    if (srcImg.size != mask.size) {
        cout << "Your two images tried to highlight have different SIZE.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    if (mask.channels() != 1)
        cvtColor(mask, mask, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    if (mask.type() != CV_8UC1)
        mask.convertTo(mask, CV_8UC1);
    threshold(mask, mask, 0, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV + THRESH_OTSU);
    cvtColor(mask, mask, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
    if (srcImg.channels() != 3)
        cvtColor(srcImg, srcImg, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
    if (srcImg.type() != CV_8UC3)
        srcImg.convertTo(srcImg, CV_8UC3);
    dilate(mask - Scalar(0, 0, 255), mask, Mat(), Point(-1, -1), 2);
    return srcImg - mask;
}
```

This is my code.

```
#include<opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
Mat highlight(Mat, Mat);
int main() {
    Mat emptyImg = imread("test.jpg", 0);
    Mat test = emptyImg.clone();

    Mat mask(5, 5, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < mask.rows; i++) {
        uchar* data = mask.ptr<uchar>(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < mask.cols; j++)
            if ((i + j) % 2 == 0)
                data[j] = 255;
    }
    resize(mask, mask, emptyImg.size(), 0, 0, INTER_NEAREST);
    Mat img1, img2,mask1,mask2;
    img1 = highlight(emptyImg, mask);
    imshow("img1", img1);
    img2 = highlight(test, mask);
    imshow("img2", img2);

    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

And this is my [test image](http://answers.opencv.org/upfiles/1511208393751086.jpg). I'm very confused. Why I will get different result like following

[image]

As my expectation, the `img1` and `img2` should be same totally. Is there anything I have miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `img1 = highlight(emptyImg, mask);` the first time, it changes the `mask` and uses it for `img1`. When you call `highlight` again, it uses this same `mask`, changing it again, and using it for `img2`. But what is the code that is causing this exactly?

`threshold(mask, mask, 0, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV + THRESH_OTSU);` is the culprit. It inverses the `mask` due to `THRESH_BINARY_INV`, then when you call it again, it inverses it once again. Remember that the `cv::Mat` is a reference variable (The `cv::Mat` acts like a pointer), so when you pass it in the parameter of a function, any changes done to it will happen to the original mat too. That's why we use `.clone()`, it creates a copy of the `cv::Mat`. The quickest fix to your program would be to `.clone()` the mask before you pass it in the function.

Boiled down code for debugging (removing the `threshold` line causes the inverted checkerboard to not happen).

```
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
Mat highlight(Mat, Mat);
int main() {
    Mat emptyImg = imread("test.jpg", 0);
    Mat test = emptyImg.clone();
    Mat mask(5, 5, CV_8UC1, Scalar(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < mask.rows; i++) {
        uchar* data = mask.ptr<uchar>(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < mask.cols; j++)
            if ((i + j) % 2 == 0)
                data[j] = 255;
    }
    resize(mask, mask, emptyImg.size(), 0, 0, INTER_NEAREST);
    Mat img1, img2, mask1, mask2;
    imshow("m1", mask);
    img1 = highlight(emptyImg, mask);
    imshow("img1", img1);
    imshow("m2", mask);
    img2 = highlight(test, mask);
    imshow("img2", img2);
    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
Mat highlight(Mat srcImg, Mat mask) {
    threshold(mask, mask, 0, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV + THRESH_OTSU);
    return srcImg - mask;
}
```